# Gaining Terminal Access to a Headless VM in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd

I am trying to figure out a means of getting FreeBSD accessible to the blind, or at least in terms of the command line (YASR maybe) and maybe throwing Emacspeak on top as a sort of desktop environment.

In order to figure out this problem, I need to have a FreeBSD VM on which to research. The problem is that since FreeBSD doesn't have any accessibility software baked in by default, I need to find a way to install the OS independently. I've done some research and discovered that VirtualBox has a headless mode that works over RDP. I am thinking that since I have a screenreader on Windows, I can connect via RDP to have the windows screenreader read out the text of the installer.

Am I getting ahead of myself, or will this work? If this won't work, do you have any ideas of what I can try?

As a side note, the goal of this project is to ensure that a blind person can:

1. Have an accessible installer so he/she can install a FreeBSD system by following the handbook, with as little added software as possible except for the base and screenreader
2. Ensure that their freshly-installed system speaks post-installation

Thoughts, comments, and critiques are most welcome.

Comment: It probably won't work as your screen reader won't actually "see" the text. At least that's my guess. I don't know how advanced they are by now. For your b) you could try to prepare a custom image that just includes the screen reader by default. In regards to a) ... no idea.

Comment: This is true; it didn't connect altogether, so I'm guessing the ISO doesn't have the necessary packages to make this happen. Nor does it have SSH, for that matter. I'll see about building one with SSH enabled by default and going from there.